# Get string and its length from file

Tags: c++, file, input, c-strings

I have a file in which I have the maximum length of the string on the first line and the string itself on the second line.
It is an educational task so I can't use the `<string>` library.
I did this:

```
ifstream input;
input.open("input.txt");
int n;
input >> n;
char* str = new char[n];
input.getline(str, n); // This is the thing i want to get rid of.
input.getline(str, n);
```

And it works, but I have to call `getline()` twice, because after I get the length with `input >> n;` there is still a `'\n'` char after it on that line, and to go to the second line of the file I have to call `getline()`, that is the only solution that I came up with. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: `std::string s;  input >> s;  std::cout << n.length();` In general, using current C++ you should not have to use new/delete much, it is not even needed to read the length of the string first. (Even if  a lot of older examples/books still show this)

Comment: "It is an educational task so I can't use library": what library? Do you mean you can't `#include <string>`?

Comment: You say your code works, so what exactly is your question?  Are you asking for other ways to achieve this?

Comment: You contradict yourself, std::ifstream (don't use `using namespace std;` by the way) is from the standard library too. So if you can use that then you can also use std::string.

Comment: (n.length() in my example should be s.length())

Comment: Tweak to above example code: `std::string s;  std::getline(input , s);  std::cout << n.length();` is closer to original code.  `>>` will read exactly one whitespace-delimited token.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica yes, i wrote <string> but it got removed for some reason, formatting issue probably.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I think I made a complicated question, so here's the thing: I cant use string type, i have to use c-strings(char arrays). I have a file in which i have smth like 
10
hello
When i get 10 with input >> n; i'm still on the same line of the file and getline() doesn't work for the first time

Comment: @SashaDynin you may still [edit] your question to clarify that you can use some standard library types, but not others.

Comment: Ahhhh. I've misread the question. You have [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21567291/4581301)

Comment: @SashaDynin "It is an educational task so I can't use library" -- The `std::string` has been an official part of C++ for 25 years now.  This is a stupid requirement, in this day and age.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `ifstream input; input.open("input.txt");` to `ifstream input("input.txt");`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I sill hope teachers will do a better job at learning C++. All in all , now that I understand the restrictions, why don't you use [`input.read(n);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) to read exactly n bytes? (Do it into a buffer of n+1 size to add the trailing '\0')

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, cin.ignore() did it for me. Now the code is better in my opninon.

```
input >> n;
cout << n << endl;
char* str = new char[n];
input.ignore();
input.getline(str, n);
```

Comment: You need to allocate n + 1 characters for a string of length n. C strings have an extra *nul terminator* character at the end.

Comment: Recommendation: don't trust a mere `ignore()`.  See the example at the end of [this documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)  for how to make sure any crap on the end of the line is eliminated along with the newline.

Comment: Good advice, but OP can't use `<string>`; I doubt `<limits>` will be okay. Anything else is a guess.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks, then I'll std::ws, it works as well. Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Does trailing whitespace count as part of the string?